# when I execute this code why error occur?

Tags: pointers, syntax-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int a=2,*p;
    p=&a;
    printf ("address of a=%u", p);
    return (0);
}
```

When I execute this code on Ubuntu it will print this error:

```
format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', 
but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-wformat].
```

Why this type of error even in code from a book? I know this is a stupid question but I'm very confused.

Comment: when you execute?  or when you compile?  and is that an error or a warning?

Comment: when I compile and its a warning

Comment: maybe that's what you should put in the post instead of saying "when I execute" and "print this error".

Comment: Its my  mistake but give me a solution of my question

Comment: the answer to your question: Why this type of error even in code from a book? is because %u expects unsigned int, and you're passing in int*.  this is a type mismatch.  it is not an error because technically it is legit c syntax.  you're just using printf  incorrectly.

Comment: you can fix this by either casting to unsigned int or using a different format spec (like %08x).

Comment: Ohk I just asked this question because its work on turbo c

Comment: ok, well you didn't tell us what compiler gave you that warning, and it still works.  you just get a warning.

Comment: Ohk then How can I run this code if its give a warning ?

Comment: the same way you run it with without warning

Comment: I give up.  Going to bed.  You should learn English before learning C.

Comment: Can u just tell me that how can I run this program without any warning.. now you get it or not

Answer (score 4):

> when I execute this code on ubuntu it will print this error:

Naw. It prints this when you **compile** it.

And that's because [`%u` is not suited for printing pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300307/why-pointer-is-giving-two-different-addresses?noredirect=1#comment28621867_19300307). Use `%p` for that purpose. **[And do read the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).**

Comment: then why it executes on turbo c ?

Comment: @user2873459 Because Turbo C is a crappy, outdated, stupid compiler which doesn't know anything about format string errors.

Comment: ohk and when I minus two addresses using pointer like
int *I,*j, a []={1, 2,3, 4};
I=&a[0];
j=&a[2];
printf ("%p", j-I);
why it will agin give error

Comment: And when I assign base address of array in pointer like p=&a; compiler again give me a warning ?

Comment: @user2873459 Because the difference of two pointers is not a pointer. It's an integer of type `ptrdiff_t` which is to be printed using `%td`. Also, As to why it warns on `p = &a`: I don't know. It shouldn't, if `a` is really an `int` and `p` is an `int *`.

Comment: Using % td compiler minus locations but I want to minus addresses ?

Comment: @user2873459 Um what? What "locations"? Aren't you subtracting pointers?

Comment: I hve subtract two pointers but but using pointer %td it subtract locactions like in my previous code ehen I subtract j-I awns ws 2 so its subtract locations but I want asnw 8 and o will print after subtractting addresses

Comment: @user2873459 That's how pointer arithmetic works. You can multiply that by `sizeof(int)` but I don't see why you would need that. Read about pointer arithmetic, I can't teach you the entire language in a comment.

Comment: I just read this program in book and when I execute this code then it prints an error thats why I asked this question

Comment: @user2873459 is that book "let us C" by any chance? If so (and not only then), throw it far away and google for a decent language tutorial. That book is terrible (it's not your fault of course, but you better don't use it.)

Comment: @user2873459 K&R for the basics, maybe Learn C The Hard Way to clean up outdated practices found in K&R. There's a "definitive C book/tutorial list" here on Stack Overflow, you can read that question/its answers as well.

Comment: @user2873459 Can you use the site search?